# Ansible `docker_container` options `network_mode` and `networks` - are they intersecting?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose, ansible-2.x

I'm building a playbook where I want to deploy a container to a host network. The [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/docker_container_module.html#docker-container) mention two options: `network_mode` and `networks`. If I want to connect my container to the default host network, is the option (syntax as in Ansible playbooks):

```
network_mode: host
```

equivalent to:

```
networks:
  name: host
```

?

If not, what would be the network to which the container connects in both cases (if it connects at all?)

Comment: What's the problem with checking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is more of a Docker question than an Ansible question.  You can find additional details beyond what I've put here in my answer by reading through, for example, the [Network settings](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) section of the `docker run` documentation.

The `networks` key allows you to connect your container to a *named network*.

The `network_mode` key allows you to select the *type* of network to create for your container (`host`, `bridge`, `none`, or the network environment of a specific container).  It doesn't allow you to connect directly to a named network.

So *if* you have a network named `host` available that uses `host` networking mode, then:

```
network_mode: host
```

Is equivalent to:

```
networks:
  - name: host
```

But in general, they let you do distinct things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Docker network already created, for example the name of your docker network is **"myAppNetwork"**, and you want to deploy a new container and connect this new container to the existing docker network then use the following Ansible configuration

```yaml
- name: Add a container to a network, leaving existing containers connected
  docker_network:
    name: myAppNetwork
    connected:
      - Backend (Your docker container name)
    appends: yes
```

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/docker_network_module.html#examples